# Is there a fast read spell in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Do we know one? Wouldn't it be nice to have one to like examines or to become more powerful? A spell like "absorbus librus" (absorb the book - where the knowledge of the book literally goes into your head on a second) or "legere abstinui" (read fast).

Wouldn't that be nice, to just absorb the book or read it very fast?

Comment: If there were, wouldn't Hermione have mentioned it? ;)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I mean this in the best possible way. All of the question body after the title is unnecessary fluff. I don't mean that as an attack, I rather enjoyed reading your prospective incantations, but whether it would be nice to have a spell, or speculating what the incantation might be, is hopelessly opinion based and not suitable for the site. The question title however *is* answerable and appropriate, although a little ... limited in audience. Always remember that SE is not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

Comment: We tend to see our purpose as organically creating a body of knowledge by providing good answers to good questions. In that sense, even though I personally often advocate for a little bit more fun on the site, we do tend to ask that questions be a little more serious and targeted. I'm telling you this because if you keep that in mind, you'll probably find people react a lot better :)

Comment: Note: _legere abstinui_ doesn't mean ‘read fast’; it means ‘I stopped/abstained from reading’.

Comment: @Adamant when I first saw the title (but hadn't loaded it so hadn't seen your comment) I was thinking something along the lines of Accio Hermione (not saying it would work) and perhaps Imperio on her making her read it and then tell you all you want to know. But I somehow doubt that's what the OP is asking even if that's the closest I know of. Of course since I can read in blocks of text I would see it differently because even if it isn't natural (it mostly is for me) it can be learned through practise (rather than say magic). But then we're talking HP so I guess that differs.

Comment: (Of course if you bring Hermione a book maybe you don't even need to force her to read it. Sounds somewhat like me although there are certain genres I won't be at all interested in.)

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your question: Nope. There isn't one in the books/movies/supplemental material to date.

Would it be nice? That can be subjective. Spells can backfire, and a person could be doomed to read/absorb too much information in too little time and overload their brain. Much like Lockhart who attempted to do something 'nice' (subjectively) in modifying Harry and Ron's memories, and instead ended up erasing his own.

AFAIK, magic can be used to enhance or alter what is already a part of a person--for example, the *Snorus* spell that Bagman/others use in *Goblet of Fire* to project their voices, or magics involving human Transfiguration like Polyjuice. It is used to grow/shrink, make a person sleepy, make a person fly, grow their bones back, etc. Magic can be used to take things away; again, Lockhart, or when Voldemort quite literally ripped up his soul. However, to my knowledge, we never see examples of magic *increasing* a 'person' in a permanent manner. We never see *additions*, however. If a wizard/witch wants to improve themselves, they have to do it the same way as Muggles--with lots of practice and studying.

Comment: It could be subjective, sure. As could improving yourself permanently. I imagine if we interviewed Voldemort he would (if we could prevent him for killing us first) say in fact his mutilated soul is an improvement. Also subjective. And didn't James suggest to Sirius that his dog form would be an improvement and to consider it permanently? He then says to Harry that the fleas are murder (which implies he would maybe consider it). But is that an improvement? I don't know but it seemed to work for Wormtail, biding his time, at least until he was revealed to be not a rat but human.